# Extract group matches with multiple possible matches in any order

Tags: r, regex

My input strings are sequences of numbers followed by one of two letters (in any order and possibly several such sequences in a row):

```
s <- c("2w", "1p", "3w1p3w", "2p12w2p3w")
```

Here is the pattern (I think) I need for that:

```
pattern <- ([0-9]+w)*([0-9]+p)*
```

However, I can't manage to get the desired output:

```
list("2w", "1p", c("3w","1p","3w"), c("2p","12w","2p","3w"))
```

I tried this:

```
(out <- regmatches(s, gregexec(pattern, s)))
```

But I do not understand the output, and I don't know how to re-format it to get what I want:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "2w"
[2,] "2w"
[3,] ""  

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,] "1p"
[2,] ""  
[3,] "1p"

[[3]]
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "3w1p" "3w"
[2,] "3w"   "3w"
[3,] "1p"   ""  

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]    [,3]
[1,] "2p" "12w2p" "3w"
[2,] ""   "12w"   "3w"
[3,] "2p" "2p"    ""
```

In the end, I want to add all the counts per letter, to get something like this:

```
data.frame(s=s, w=c(2,0,6,15), p=c(0,1,1,4))
          s  w p
1        2w  2 0
2        1p  0 1
3    3w1p3w  6 1
4 2p12w2p3w 15 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

even more simple: split the string after every `p` or `w` (and keep the delimiter)

```
s <- c("2w", "1p", "3w1p3w", "2p12w2p3w")
ans <- strsplit(s, "(?<=[pw])", perl=TRUE)
 
# [[1]]
# [1] "2w"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1p"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "3w" "1p" "3w"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "2p"  "12w" "2p"  "3w"
```

second part

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(ans, as.data.table), idcol = "id")
DT[, c("value", "letter") := tstrsplit(V1, "(?=[wp])", perl=TRUE, type.convert = TRUE)]
dcast(DT[, .(sum(value)), by = .(id, letter)],id ~ letter, value.var = "V1", fill = 0)[, id := s][]
#           id p  w
# 1:        2w 0  2
# 2:        1p 1  0
# 3:    3w1p3w 1  6
# 4: 2p12w2p3w 4 15
```

Answer (score 3):

I think we can go more simple?

```r
regmatches(s, gregexpr("[0-9]+[^0-9]", s))
# [[1]]
# [1] "2w"
# [[2]]
# [1] "1p"
# [[3]]
# [1] "3w" "1p" "3w"
# [[4]]
# [1] "2p"  "12w" "2p"  "3w"
```

We can create that summarizing frame with a little more effort.

Base R (mostly):

```r
s2 <- regmatches(s, gregexpr("[0-9]+[^0-9]", s))
strcapture("([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)", unlist(s2), list(num=0L, ltr="")) |>
  transform(row = rep(seq_along(s2), times=lengths(s2))) |>
  reshape2::dcast(row ~ ltr, data = _, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "num") |>
  transform(s = s, row = NULL)
#   p  w         s
# 1 0  2        2w
# 2 1  0        1p
# 3 1  6    3w1p3w
# 4 4 15 2p12w2p3w
```

dplyr/tidyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
strcapture("([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)", unlist(s2), list(num=0L, ltr="")) |>
  mutate(row = rep(seq_along(s2), times=lengths(s2))) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = row, names_from = ltr, values_from = num, values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0) |>
  mutate(s = s, row = NULL)
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#       w     p s        
#   <int> <int> <chr>    
# 1     2     0 2w       
# 2     0     1 1p       
# 3     6     1 3w1p3w   
# 4    15     4 2p12w2p3w
```

Comment: Thanks very much! But I think that the solution with strsplit is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here are base R option for your two questions

- For Question 1

```
> regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+\\D+", s))
[[1]]
[1] "2w"

[[2]]
[1] "1p"

[[3]]
[1] "3w" "1p" "3w"

[[4]]
[1] "2p"  "12w" "2p"  "3w"
```

- For Question 2

```
reshape(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      s,
      \(x)  {
        u <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+\\D+", x))[[1]]
        cbind(
          id = x,
          stack(
            by(as.integer(gsub("\\D+", "", u)), gsub("\\d+", "", u), sum)
          )
        )
      }
    )
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "id",
  timevar = "ind"
)
```

gives

```
         id values.w values.p
1        2w        2       NA
2        1p       NA        1
3    3w1p3w        6        1
5 2p12w2p3w       15        4
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer matches the substrings of interest but also verifies the string has the following properties:

- the string is comprised of one or more contiguous substrings;
- each substring consists of one or two digits followed by the letter `'w'` or `'p'`;
- the letters must alternate from one substring to the next; and
- the letter in the first substring may be `'w'` or `'p'`.

The following regular expression can be used (with `perl=TRUE` invoked).

```
^(?=\d{1,2}([wp])(?:\d{1,2}(?!\1)[wp]\d{1,2}\1)*(?:\d{1,2}(?!\1)[wp])?$)\d{1,2}[wp]|(?!^)\G\d{1,2}[wp]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mMnzP/1)

---

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^            # match beginning of string
(?=          # begin positive lookahead
  \d{1,2}    # match 1 or 2 digits
  ([wp])     # match 'w' or 'p' and save to capture group 1
  (?:        # begin non-capture group
    \d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits
    (?!\1)   # negative lookahead asserts next char does not equal the
             # contents of capture group 1 
    [wp]     # match 'w' or 'p'
    \d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits
    \1       # match the contents of capture group 1
  )*         # end non-capture group and execute >= 0 times
  (?:        # begin non-capture group
    \d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits
    (?!\1)   # negative lookahead asserts next char does not equal the
             # contents of capture group 1 
    [wp]     # match 'w' or 'p'
  )?         # end non-capture group and make it optional
  $          # match end of string
)            # end positive lookahead
\d{1,2}[wp]  # match 1 or 2 digits followed by 'w' or 'p'
|            # or
(?!^)        # negative lookahead asserts current location is not the
             # start of the string
\G           # begin current match at end of previous match
\d{1,2}[wp]  # match 1 or 2 digits followed by 'w' or 'p'
```

Note that the positive lookahead verifies the string has the correct format and nothing more.